# Google Analytics: Incorrect results showing within view

Tags: google-analytics

I have a property setup that has two main views: sitea.com view and siteb.com view, note that the property default URL is sitea.com.

When I go to the reporting tab for the siteb.com view, and navigate to Acquisition > Social > Landing pages, the shared URL shows both sitea.com results and siteb.com results despite me being in the siteb.com view.

How can I restrict the results so that they only show siteb.com? I added a filter to the view that excluded anything containing siteb.com but when I verified the filter it said that there were no changes to the results.

Comment: The default domain only affects the (soon to be removed) in page analysis and the page preview feature, it has no effect on data collection. You'd need to post a screenshot of your filter configuration - filter by hostname is indeed the way  to go, we can just assume that some glitch prevents the filter from working. In the meantime you can do segments based on hostname, which would allow you to access data per domain in a single view.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about usage of the Google Analytics website and is not programing related. may be better suited for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @EikePierstorff See pictures: http://imgur.com/a/7gKyu The first shows gfcmediagroup,com appearing in the results, and the second shows the filter that I thought would filter out gfcmediagroup.com results.

Comment: @DaImTo Apologies, I had seen similar GA questions on here so thought it was ok.

Comment: Jimmy, I've been on SO for more than four years now and I still can't always remember the rules, so I guess you are excused :-) But DaImTo is right, this would indeed be a better fit for webmasters.

Comment: As for your filter, for some reason the predefined filters have never worked for me - you could try to do an advanced filter and exclude by the hostname field.

Comment: @EikePierstorff I will post it there :) Thanks for the tip, I created an advanced filter (assuming you mean custom?) but unfortunately it did not have the desired effect.